# crystal report - sql query in formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-xi

I have a formula field in my Crystal Report and wondering if I can put a query/subquery logic behind it.

For example, currently now I have this on my formula field:

```
IF ({MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN} in ['VALUE1','VALUE2'])
    THEN "OK"
ELSE
    "NOTOK"
```

As you can see the VALUE1 and VALUE2 are currently hardcoded there, what if I want these values queried from the database, is it possible?  Something like this:

```
IF ({MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN} in [SELECT QUERY GOES HERE....])
    THEN "OK"
ELSE
    "NOTOK"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can get this subquery as a field in your procedure

Comment: As @Zeina said, add the code of the subquery in your sql command that brings the data to your report in a way that the command will bring two more fields: these of VALUE1,VALUE2. Then add theese two new fileds in your formula and you are done. In case you have more difficulty in doing that, you should show us more code e.g your subquery and your main sql command

Comment: heard about sql expression field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609589/converting-sql-statement-to-sql-expression-field-in-crystal-reports